# Python populating input arguments for a function with *args

Tags: python, function, arguments, args, keyword-argument

If I have a function which supports variable argument number, i.e. uses *args, how can I populate the arguments from a loop/list comprehension? Say the function expects multiple lists as arguments and I have a table/dataframe and want to use each column as an input argument, why does this not work?

`funName([df[iCol].values for iCol in df.columns])`

Say my dataframe has 5 columns, I would be required to call the function like so:

`funName(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)`

But I do not want to manually create variables for each column but rather populate the argument list dynamically. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unpack your list when passing it in:

`funName(*[df[iCol].values for iCol in df.columns])`

List unpacking is required because if you don't, `fn` will get a single argument, which is a list, say `[1, 2, 3]`, and you want a sequence of arguments `1, 2, 3`.

For example:

```
>>> def fn(*args):
...     print args
...     
>>> fn([1, 2, 3])
([1, 2, 3],)
>>> fn(*[1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! Why is list unpacking required? (will accept the answer in 11 mins).

Comment: @dter That's the syntax

Comment: Makes sense. Basically identifying whether the 1,2,3 is 3 different arguments or 1 argument list containing [1,2,3] as elements.